# External Hard drive Compatibility

Tags: external-hdd

Does anyone know if a FreeAgent Desk External Drive by Seagate 1.5 TB with USB 2.0 is compatible with Ubuntu? or even which version of Ubuntu. I know very little, I'm reading through previous answers and am lost. I'm buying an old external Hard drive(still in a sealed box) to rescue files from a old failing computer, to transfer to a little less older computer that soon will only be able to run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not know about this make and mode and its capability to Ubuntu. However, in the past I have never had any issues with any of the HDD's (new and old), that I have connected to my Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Completely agree with Phil, I never had any problem connecting even 6 years old 2TB disk on Ubuntu 12.04. It will work.